# How can I Import Java Code into MPS-BaseLang?

Tags: java, mps

I'd like to import existing Java code (say, an Eclipse project) into MPS. The code should be parsed into MPS' BaseLang, so that I can analyze and transform it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on a model and choose "Get Model Contents From Source". This should run the MPS-to-Java importer. Untested, though.

Comment: Is there any support to do this for your own language? Or do I need to write my own parser?

Comment: @Kirilian you need to write a parser.

Comment: Pain. That seems like an insane amount of work. So basically all MPS generated text is only one way? No way to read the text output back.

Comment: Yes, no free lunch here unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can also copy some java code into the buffer, right click on a spot in a function or in a class and then choose "Paste as Java Class Content" to import java code.